# I've been using dictionary keys as membership markers. Is this a good idea?

Tags: python

For instance, I have a document that has a pile of control codes that I need to manually specify replacements for. I basically write a script that prints out the list of codes. Easy.

Now I've been using a dictionary's key to store the membership. If the code exists, then I set the dictionary value to something, and then I just return the keys of that dictionary. This strikes me as a little wasteful. Is there any better way of doing things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead.

```
>>> members = set()
>>> members.add(1)
>>> 1 in members
True
>>> 2 in members
False
```

If your codes are stored in an iterable then finding the unique codes might be as as simple as:

```
>>> set(codes)
```

Comment: What's the complexity of checking membership?

Comment: @Alex: Like a dict, a set uses a hash check first, and then an equality test. In the (normal) situation where you have few collisions a membership test is approximately O(1) for all practical purposes. This is the same as finding a key in a dict.

Comment: @Alex: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.  Average: O(1), Worst: O(n).